# Print the objects that contain USDT

Tags: python, json

I would like to print only objects that contain USDT from:

```
requestT = requests.get('https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price')
json_data = json.loads(requestT.text)
print(json_data)
```

Example:

```
data = [{'symbol': 'BNBETH', 'price': '0.16540000'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '64321.11000000'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '3330.76000000'}]
```

Result:

```
data1 = [{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '64321.11000000'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '3330.76000000'}]
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: thank you, all three variants work perfectly. I took the second one and I don't even know why hehe thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the data for example with list-comprehension:

```py
import requests

json_data = requests.get("https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price").json()

usdt_data = [d for d in json_data if "USDT" in d["symbol"]]
print(*usdt_data, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
...

{'symbol': 'PDAUSDT', 'price': '0.12620000'}
{'symbol': 'AXLUSDT', 'price': '1.88250000'}
{'symbol': 'WIFUSDT', 'price': '2.26590000'}
{'symbol': 'METISUSDT', 'price': '97.19000000'}
{'symbol': 'AEVOUSDT', 'price': '2.39000000'}
{'symbol': 'BOMEUSDT', 'price': '0.01351400'}
{'symbol': 'ETHFIUSDT', 'price': '4.02700000'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always ensure that your HTTP request succeeded before trying to do anything with the response.

You could use a lambda for this but my preference is a discrete function.

So...

```
import requests

def usdt(d):
    return "USDT" in d.get("symbol", "")

with requests.get("https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price") as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    result = list(filter(usdt, response.json()))
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, all three variants work perfectly. I took this one and I don't even know why :):) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

based on your hoped for result, I wrote a fairly simple solution, where I create a new list containing the matches inside it, in the code I also commented the various steps for a better understanding, obviously there are many ways to obtain the same result, this method is the most basic

**Code.py**

```
import json

data = [{'symbol': 'BNBETH', 'price': '0.16540000'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '64321.11000000'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '3330.76000000'}]

new_data = []

for usdt in data:
    
    # here you check if "USDT" is inside the "symbol" key of each result
    
    if 'USDT' in usdt['symbol']:
        
        # if it exists, I insert every single match into the new list
        new_data.append(usdt)
        

# I call the output with indent=4 for better reading

print(json.dumps(new_data, indent=4))
```

**result:**

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
        "price": "64321.11000000"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "ETHUSDT",
        "price": "3330.76000000"
    }
]
```

I hope I have been of help to you.

Comment: according to my description, you can also use indexing